# If category is 'x' add class

Tags: jquery, wordpress, categories, addclass

Morning all,

Just a quick question, within the loop I would like to check if an element has the category 'nolink' if so add class.

...

My code is below. I would like the jquery to remove the class `client-hover` if the `a` attribute is `#.` But it doesn't appear to work.

Many thanks

```
<?php 
query_posts( 'category_name=projects' );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $href = ( has_term( 'nolink', 'category' ) ) ? '#' : get_permalink();
        echo '<div class="grid_3">';
        echo '<a href="' . $href . '">';
            echo '<ul class="work-thumb-wrap client-hover post_class();">';
                echo '<li class="work-popup">';
                    echo '<p>';
                        echo 'View Client Work';
                    echo '</p>';
                echo '</li>';
                echo '<li class="work-img">';
                    echo '<img src="';
                        echo the_field('client_thumb');
                    echo '">';
                echo '</li>';
            echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if($('href').attr('#') === null) { 
        $('.work-thumb-wrap').removeClass('client-hover');
    }

    $('.work-thumb-wrap').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children('.work-popup').animate({'bottom' : '0px'}, 200);
    });

    $('.work-thumb-wrap').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('.work-popup').animate({'bottom' : '-40px'}, 200);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you want to add the class to?

Comment: Id rather use what I have just made, so remove class 'client-hover' if a href is #.

Comment: Ok chaps, thank you for making me think more about this. Rather than just asking you chaps. I have sorted it by using "if (has_category('nolink')) echo " nohover";"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first JavaScript `if` is all wrong. You should do it like this:

Imperatively:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') {
        $(this).find('.work-thumb-wrap').removeClass('client-hover');
    }
});
```

Or just simply:

```
$('a[href="#"] .work-thumb-wrap').removeClass('client-hover');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('a[href="#"]').removeClass('client-hover');
```

Instead of

```
if($('href').attr('#') === null) { 
    $('.work-thumb-wrap').removeClass('client-hover');
}
```

Comment: OP needs to remove the class from the `ul`, not the `a`

Comment: That does work, just tried thank you! but my comment above also works. thank you Kasyx